# get path of the file the module is being called from?

Tags: node.js, module, path

Let's say I have a node.js module

```
module.exports = function () {
  console.log(__filename);
}
```

And in the main file I call it like

```
var x = require('path/to/module');
x();
```

That gives me the path to the module file. For example if I stored the module at `~/project-root/lib/mod.js` and the `main.js` file lies at `~/project-root/main.js`, that setup gives me the output:

```
~/project-root/lib/mod.js
```

I want to use something in place of `__filename` in the module that gives me to location of of the file from which it was called from. (e.g. the output would be `~/project-root/main.js` instead, in this example).

The module can be located anywhere. So using `path` to adjust for only this example would fail in other scenarios (for example if module is stored in `~/project-root/node_modules/` or the global node.js modules directory.

*I have a feeling it's something fairly trivial and I'm overlooking something. But I haven't found a solution from anything Google has yielded during an hour long search. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords!*

Answer (score 2):

[Module.parent](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent) called in your module lets you access to the `exports` of the file it was called from.

You can put the function below in your `main.js` and you can call `module.parent.filename()` in your module.

`module.exports.filename = function () {
  return __filename;
}`

Comment: You see the module has to be public, so anyone can do `npm install my-module`. I am looking for a solution that doesn't require the user i.e. the person who's *using* that module to have to do any patching to make the module work. The `Module.parent` bit is interesting. Is there a way to access the parent even if the parent (i.e. `main.js`) doesn't export anything?

Comment: theoretically you can access `module.parent.filename`

Comment: one caveat is that it will only return the **first** parent that required current module

Comment: `module.parent` also has the parent attribute, so it **isn't** limited to the first parent (tested on node v0.10.30). so you can (theoretically) `module.parent.filename`, `module.parent.parent.filename`, `module.parent.parent.parent.filename`, etc...

Comment: @matteospampani what soulcheck meant is that if you have foo.js and bar.js and they both require foobar.js the first one to require foobar.js will be the parent. So if foo.js requires it first the parent will always foo.js.